# Combine strings separated by multiple lines

Tags: r

I have a set of strings which has an ID that starts with `>`. I would like to get the strings that follow each ID on one line, and not separate on multiple lines like they are now. The string can sometimes be separated on 1,2 or 3 lines.

```
fileName="hairpin"
conn=file(fileName,open="r")
linn=readLines(conn)
for (i in 1:length(linn)){
 print(linn[i])
}
close(conn)
head(linn)

[1] ">cel-let-7 MI0000001 Caenorhabditis elegans let-7 stem-loop" 
[2] "UACACUGUGGAUCCGGUGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUUUGGAAUAUUACCACCGGUGAAC"
[3] "UAUGCAAUUUUCUACCUUACCGGAGACAGAACUCUUCGA"                     
[4] ">cel-lin-4 MI0000002 Caenorhabditis elegans lin-4 stem-loop" 
[5] "AUGCUUCCGGCCUGUUCCCUGAGACCUCAAGUGUGAGUGUACUAUUGAUGCUUCACACCU"
[6] "GGGCUCUCCGGGUACCAGGACGGUUUGAGCAGAU
```

output

```
[1] ">cel-let-7 MI0000001 Caenorhabditis elegans let-7 stem-loop"  "UACACUGUGGAUCCGGUGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUUUGGAAUAUUACCACCGGUGAACUAUGCAAUUUUCUACCUUACCGGAGACAGAACUCUUCGA"                     
[4] ">cel-lin-4 MI0000002 Caenorhabditis elegans lin-4 stem-loop"  "AUGCUUCCGGCCUGUUCCCUGAGACCUCAAGUGUGAGUGUACUAUUGAUGCUUCACACCUGGGCUCUCCGGGUACCAGGACGGUUUGAGCAGAU"
```

I found the solution in anothet website:

```
 awk '/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n",$0);next; } { printf("%s",$0);}  END {printf("\n");}' < file.fa
```

Comment: What does the actual data in the file look like?

Comment: the data is downloaded from here: ftp://mirbase.org/pub/mirbase/CURRENT/hairpin.fa.gz

Comment: they are not separated because of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
g <- cumsum(grepl("^>", Lines)) # equals 1 for first group, 2 for second, etc.
unname(unlist(tapply(Lines, g, function(x) c(x[1], paste(x[-1], collapse = "")))))
```

giving:

```
[1] ">cel-let-7 MI0000001 Caenorhabditis elegans let-7 stem-loop"                                        
[2] "UACACUGUGGAUCCGGUGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUUUGGAAUAUUACCACCGGUGAACUAUGCAAUUUUCUACCUUACCGGAGACAGAACUCUUCGA"
[3] ">cel-lin-4 MI0000002 Caenorhabditis elegans lin-4 stem-loop"                                        
[4] "AUGCUUCCGGCCUGUUCCCUGAGACCUCAAGUGUGAGUGUACUAUUGAUGCUUCACACCUGGGCUCUCCGGGUACCAGGACGGUUUGAGCAGAU"
```

**Note** The input `Lines` is:

```
Lines <- c(">cel-let-7 MI0000001 Caenorhabditis elegans let-7 stem-loop",
"UACACUGUGGAUCCGGUGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUUUGGAAUAUUACCACCGGUGAAC",
"UAUGCAAUUUUCUACCUUACCGGAGACAGAACUCUUCGA",
">cel-lin-4 MI0000002 Caenorhabditis elegans lin-4 stem-loop",
"AUGCUUCCGGCCUGUUCCCUGAGACCUCAAGUGUGAGUGUACUAUUGAUGCUUCACACCU",
"GGGCUCUCCGGGUACCAGGACGGUUUGAGCAGAU")
```